# UITextView disappears behind keyboard after typing a while

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios9, uikeyboard

We're trying to support iOS 9 for a while yet... That's the only place this is happening...

I have a `UITextView` that occupies the entire view, which occupies the entire screen. I register to receive `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`. I get those just fine and adjust the height of my UITextView so that it is above the keyboard:

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
    {
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    bounds.size.height = bounds.size.height - keyboardRect.size.height;
    self.textView.frame = bounds;
    }
```

Again, this works great. Now I type a few lines. For a while, the bottom line of text is kept above the keyboard automatically as I add more lines of text. But eventually, usually within just a few lines (maybe 4-5), the next line will go under the keyboard and I can continue typing lines under the keyboard. Eventually the lines I can still see above the keyboard will start scrolling up as I hit the bottom of the screen with the lines I'm typing behind the keyboard.

I am not getting the `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` during this process, but it is almost behaving like I am -- that is, the size of my `UITextView` appears to return to its original size before the keyboard was shown.

All of this works fine in iOS 11. That is, as I type, the text scrolls up so the bottom line of text never goes behind the keyboard. It's just iOS 9. Anybody remember a known issue back in those days, and a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you're mixing Autolayout w/ Autoresizing and it seems to be picking the *intended* one in later iOS's but not in iOS 9.

A quick sample using your code + auto layout constraints in the  storyboard resulted in what I believe to be the behavior you're seeing in older iOS's (iOS 9.3 Simulator shown below):

[image: AutoResizing+AutoLayout_iOS9]

If I roll with a pure auto layout approach (i.e. IBOutlet the textView's bottom constraint and adjust the constant for that programmatically in keyboardWillShow) then it results in the correct behavior on iOS 9 (no setFrame call):

[image: Pure_AutoLayout_iOS9]

```
@property (strong, nullable) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *textViewBottomConstraint;

...

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    self.textViewBottomConstraint.constant = -keyboardRect.size.height;
}
```

Comment: Excellent observation. I actually don't use Autolayout at all but this particular nib had the Autolayout box checked for some reason. It's a fairly old file -- based on version control it existed before 2011 (earliest code in the app is from 2008, not counting the C++ from 1998). I suspect that in one of the XCode updates it reformatted the file and turned Autolayout on by default. I turned that off and it started behaving correctly in both iOS 9 and iOS 11. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Glad that helped.  It could be that with the Autolayout box checked it was translating the Autoresizing masks into constraints, which were then in contest with the programmatically added ones in `keyboardWillShow`.